# Filter array of objects using another array of objects, then group results as indexed array of indexed arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, filtering, grouping

I have a multi dimensional array that I wanted to print in a for loop. The first array dimension E.g `$arrayName[0]` has a array size 2 and keys starts from `0 => value1`, then `1 => value2`. Then `$arrayName[1]` with array size 2 also but the keys starts in sequence with the first array dimension, it looks like this `2 => value3` and `3 => value4`. Instead of 2 and 3 keys, is there a way that I can make it 0 and 1 since it is another 2nd array dimension? Please help me with this. Thanks. Please look at the image below.

[image]

I want it to be like this

[image]

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($qualified_applicants); $i++) { 
    for ($j = 0; $j < count($appExp); $j++) { 
        if ($qualified_applicants[$i]->id == $appExp[$j]->applicant_id){
            $temp[$appExp[$j]->applicant_id][$j] = $appExp[$j]->work.', '.$appExp[$j]->company_name.' - '.date("F j, Y", strtotime($appExp[$j]->start_date)).' - '.date("F j, Y", strtotime($appExp[$j]->end_date));
        } else {
            //                          
        }
    }
    # code...
}
```

Above is my code in creating a multidimensional array.

Comment: Did you create this array? If so, can you share the code you created it with?

Comment: why use a for loop ? why not foreach ?

Comment: Please paste code that creates this array

Comment: @Eli can you share your code

Comment: please make a proper array first that you want to reset and update your question with that

Comment: as i notice with your question i think you need to use array_values() that is used for set array with 0 to so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$arr1 = array(
    array(
        "i m first value of 0th array",
        "i m Second value of 0th array"
    ), 
    array(
        2 => "I m first value of 1st array but my key started with 2 and i want to start it with 0", 
        3 => "I m Second value of 1st array but my key is 3 and i want to set it with 1"
    )
);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($arr1); // array before

// above is you array i as understand

$newFormattedArray = array();

foreach($arr1 as $key => $value){
    $newFormattedArray[$key] = array_values($value); // array_values() will set the order in asc, starts with 0
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($newFormattedArray); // array after
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than adding another loop to call `array_values()` on each subarray (which for the record can be `array_map('array_values', $yourArray)`), it will be better to refactor and streamline your initial filtering and grouping approach.

Create a lookup array from the `$qualified_applicants` array since it will logically only have unique `id` values.

Then you can avoid running nested loops by checking if each `$appExp` qualifies.  Using temporary keys in your result array will maintain the intended grouping.  After the loop is finished, call `array_values()` to re-index the first level keys.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/UH1lp))

```
$lookup = array_flip(array_column($qualified_applicants, 'id'));
$result = [];
foreach ($appExp as $obj) {
    if (isset($lookup[$obj->applicant_id])) {
        $result[$obj->applicant_id][] = sprintf(
            '%s, %s - %s - %s',
            $obj->applicant_id,
            $obj->work,
            $obj->company_name,
            date("F j, Y", strtotime($obj->start_date)),
            date("F j, Y", strtotime($obj->end_date))
        );
    }
}
var_export(array_values($result));
```